# insert to sqlite false

Tags: android, sqlite

Can someone help me whith this?
[how-to-insert-data-into-a-sqlite-database-in-android](http://mrbool.com/how-to-insert-data-into-a-sqlite-database-in-android/28895)

I cannot understand and find out why the result of the insert is not displayed at the main page of the app.
I do the insert of the new student but after i cannot see my new insert.I also have checked the sql file and shows that every time i make a new insert only the id is created and the name(the data i input) still blank,like i have not typed anything.

What happens?

Edit (this is the insert):

```
    public void insertRecord(HashMap<String, String> queryValues) {
  SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
  ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
  values.put("Name", queryValues.get("name"));
  database.insert("student", null, values);
  database.close();
}
```

(but i don't think that this is the problem)

Comment: Have you implemented some code? If you have then paste here.

Comment: i use the code as it is at the example on the link, should i post the same code here too?

Comment: OK...So nothing displayed or inserted?

Comment: Yes nothing just the id is created for every row automatically but the data i input is not inserted and so not displayed.

Comment: Show your code that calls `insertRecord`.

Comment: Ok i have edited my post,please check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have go through the code and found some case sensitive errors of database column names.

Inside the `onCreate` method of `MainActivity` find the following line

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter( MainActivity.this,studentList, R.layout.view_student_entry, new String[] { "studentId","studentName"}, new int[] {R.id.studentId, R.id.studentName});
```

it should be

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter( MainActivity.this,studentList, R.layout.view_student_entry, new String[] { "StudentId","StudentName"}, new int[] {R.id.studentId, R.id.studentName});
```

What I changed is capital "S" instead of simple "s" of "StudentId" and "StudentName"

and there should be another change

go and find the "addNewStudent" method of new Student method

then change the following line

```
queryValues.put("studentName", studentName.getText().toString());
```

to

```
queryValues.put("StudentName", studentName.getText().toString());
```

Your column name of data entering should be exactly same as database column name.

Now it's done... enjoy the code.....

Comment: Thank you very much sometimes i lost the simple things.Thank's again very helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

Try to print the value which your passing through the object like this

```
 public void insertRecord(HashMap<String, String> queryValues) {
 System.out.println("PASSED VALUE :"+queryValues.get("name"));
// If this line prints empty value then that will store the record empty in that field.So try to pass the actual value.
  SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
  ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
  values.put("Name", queryValues.get("name"));
  database.insert("student", null, values);
  database.close();
}
```

Comment: I have tried this through logcat but nothing happend because of the problem that found and solved by @Dehan Wijesekara .Thank's although for your time and help.